# PHP time range validation

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently working on my PHP page that includes scheduling. I am planning to include a validation that will limit the user to input same or between the time ranges as the other schedules under a single classroom.

For better understanding,

If this schedule is present on the database `Schedule 1 : MWF 9:00am - 10:00am; Room 1`

Neither

`Schedule 2 : Wednesday 9:00am - 10:00am; Room 1` nor
`Schedule 3: MWF 9:30am - 10:30am; Room 1` is allowed to be entered.

Can you give me idea to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a `start_time` and `end_time`, whenever a new item is getting added you should not find any existing items such that:

```
start_time  BETWEEN new_item_start_time AND new_item_end_time
OR end_time BETWEEN new_item_start_time AND new_item_end_time
```